# NHibernate issues redundant queries with composite keys

Tags: nhibernate, composite-key, composite-id

For the sake of the example, let's say that I have to model the "person" entity of the database of my country's revenue service, and that in my very small country the first name and the last name of a person are enough to uniquely identify the person. Additionally, the revenue service's database does not use surrogate keys, and adding a surrogate key to it would zero out the GDP of the country for the next 10 years.

The *Persons* table has three fields:

- *FirstName*
- *LastName*
- *CurrentAddress*

And, given the size of my country, the table has a *unique* constraint on the <*FirstName*, *LastName*> pair of columns.

Given this schema, my very simple *Person* class has the following members:

- *Key*: an instance of a *PersonKey* class, which in turn has *FirstName* and *LastName* members, and of course implements *Equals()* and *GetHashCode()*;
- *CurrentAddress*: a simple string.

The NHibernate mapping looks as follows:

```
<class name="Person" table="Persons" lazy="false">    

  <composite-id name="Key" class="PersonKey">
    <key-property name="FirstName" type="string" column="FirstName"/>
    <key-property name="LastName" type="string" column="LastName"/>
  </composite-id>

  <property name="CurrentAddress" type="string" column="CurrentAddress" not-null="true" />

</class>
```

So far so good, this mapping works fine and I can happily load *Person* entities from the DB.

However, when I look under the hood, I can see that when loading the entire set of persons, NHibernate does the following:

1. Opens a recordset to load key properties only (i.e. exclusively the *FirstName* and *LastName* fields) from the *Persons* table;
2. For each <*FirstName*, *LastName*> pair loaded from *Persons*, it issues a SELECT - of course against *Persons* as well -  to load the CurrentAddress for the person having that *FirstName* and *LastName*.

In other words, NHibernate is first loading the keys, and then it issues a series of SELECT's to load each *Person* separately providing the key in the WHERE clause.

Provided that I am not interested in *writing* to the database, is there a way to tell NHibernate that it could use a single recordset to retrieve **both** key and non-key properties from the table?

Comment: Update: this happens only when I use `IQuery.Enumerable()`. If I use `IQuery.List()` NHibernate does the smart thing and only queries the table once. However, when I have 3.7 gazillions of persons in the table and my app only needs to process a person at a time, storing all persons in a list is a _bit_ overkill.

Comment: how does it behave when you use `IQuery.Future<Person>()` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `IQuery.Future<Person>()` behaves differently depending on the driver's capabilities. If I use a driver that does not support multiple queries, but which supports multiple result sets (e.g. OdbcDriver), then `::Future()` operates exactly like `::List()`. On the other hand, if the driver supports multiple queries and no multiple result sets (e.g. SqlClientDriver), then `::Future()` reads the entire recordset in memory (killing the app). Unfortunately NHibernate does not ship with a driver for SQL Server that supports both multiple queries and multiple record sets.

Comment: Update: even if I had a driver that supported both, it appears that `IQuery.Future<Person>()` would load all results in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IQuery.Enumerable` has the behavior you mentioned in your comment (loads the keys first, the elements on MoveNext)

In any case, NH is not designed for the mass-processing scenario you are trying to create.

You'll have much better performance by using a raw DataReader.

Comment: Thanks Diego, that's what I feared and what I've been suspecting so far.